# UINavigationController embedded inside UITabBarController Swift

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UINavigationController embedded inside a UITabBarController with 3 segues going from the TabBarController to the NavigationViewController. I have narrowed down the crash to one line of code. In MyTabBarController class, the following line is causing the app to crash:

```
let vc  = viewControllers[index] as MyNavigationController
```

I am seeing the error code: Thread1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_i386_BPT,subcode=0x0)
It's not giving me anything specific

Here is MyTabBarController class:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let podcasts = Podcast.podcasts()
    for i in 0..<podcasts.count {
        setupViewController(i, podcast: podcasts[i])
    }
}

func setupViewController(index: Int, podcast: Podcast) {
    let vc  = viewControllers[index] as MyNavigationController
    vc.podcast = podcast
    vc.tabBarItem.title = "Episode \(podcast.episodeNumber)"
    vc.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "\(podcast.episodeNumber).png")
}
```

}

Comment: What is the question? What is not working? What is the error message? What are you expecting?

Comment: I am seeing the error code: Thread1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_i386_BPT,subcode=0x0) It's not giving me anything specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. There was something wrong with the storyboard. I deleted the UINavigationController and the UITabBarController and I re-embedded and redid the connections and it worked.